# Can Google App users view Exchange users public calendars and contacts?

Tags: exchange, g-suite, calendar, public-folders, contacts

My company currently uses MS Exchange 2003 for company email, contacts, and calendars.  We have approximately 150 users.  Construction industry.

I would like to look into migrating from Exchange to Google Apps.  It will be an easier sell to the powers that be if we can migrate certain smaller departments first successfully than an entire company move.

I would like to first migrate our field superintendents who are usually out of the office working remotely.  Approx 30 users.

Will Google App users be able to see our Exchange user's calendars and vice versa?  How about public folders?  Anyone's migration story is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, Google discourages the use of Outlook so make sure that your company is willing to part with that tool. We experienced a lot of user friction around the conversation view so I highly recommend training for all users. Uploading existing mailboxes will take days in many cases so if you can start with a clean mailbox. We configured Outlook with PST of their old mail and the ability to forward old messages to their new mailbox. Our environment: 6 continents, 56 domains, 2700 users.

Answer (score 1):

Here's Google's Outlook/Exchange Q/A on integration:
http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33322

Looks like there's several options at your disposal, namely Google Calendar Connectors.